How do you apply the hair asset modifiers when using a subdivision surface modifier?
Is there any way I can get the hair to conform to the subdivided object without applying the subdivided surface modifier? I'm hoping to retain a simple topology for future animation.


Yes. Duplicate the mesh with the same modifier stack for generation (but without deformation), then transfer the hidden rest_position attribute
